# Why isn't it require to declare method viewDidLoad, viewDidUnload, etc.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm extremely new to xcode and objective c.  I realize that we only declare methods in the .h file if we want it public to other classes.  I also noticed that we can use class extensions in the .m file to make a method "private".  But how is it that some methods aren't declared anywhere (such as viewDidLoad, etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are methods of the superclass - `UIViewController`.  They are declared in the interface for that class.  When you inherit from that class, you inherit all of its method declarations and implementations.

Comment: I would add that viewDidLoad is declared in UIViewController.h, which is part of the UIKit framework. UIKit is included in most project templates by default, and if you look in your class .h files, you'll probably see that UIKit.h is referenced. UIKit.h includes UIViewController.h. This is how the compiler knows that viewDidLoad exists when it compiles your project.

Comment: The import of the header file is how the compiler knows that the selector exists, which is necessary but not sufficient. The compiler also needs to know that your class wants to respond to that selector, otherwise your implementation and/or any users of your class may get warnings or errors (depending on your settings—also, autocomplete won't handle the method, etc.). Inheritance is what takes care of that part. So I think Jim's answer is the important part.

Comment: In addition, `-viewDidLoad` is a delegate method, and its selector is basically hardcoded into AppKit/UIKit. Since your own code isn't calling `-viewDidLoad` itself, it really wouldn't be necessary to declare it in a header (i.e. doing so would not suppress any warnings or make sure that the proper return type was used).